M3 Theming Not Applied Unless Using mat.all-component-themes?
I've upgraded to v18 and am using M3.  While updating the theming I tested it quickly with  @include mat.all-component-themes($_light-theme), which worked, but when trying to customize the theme and reduce bundle size by including components individually doesn't appear to work as expected.  For example, components like menu, select, and datepicker drop downs are transparent with no background.  I'm using the light theme generated by the CLI from our colours:
$_light-theme: mat.define-theme(
  (
    color: (
      theme-type: light,
      primary: $_primary,
      tertiary: $_tertiary,
      use-system-variables: true,
    ),
    typography: (
      use-system-variables: true,
    ),
  )
);

:root {
  // Worked as expected
  // @include mat.all-component-themes($_light-theme);

  // No backgrounds on menu, select, datepicker, etc
  @include mat.core-theme($_light-theme);

  @include mat.system-level-colors($_light-theme);
  @include mat.system-level-typography($_light-theme);

  @include mat.button-theme($_light-theme);
  @include mat.card-theme($_light-theme);
  @include mat.datepicker-theme($_light-theme);
  @include mat.dialog-theme($_light-theme);
  @include mat.divider-theme($_light-theme);
  @include mat.form-field-theme($_light-theme);
  @include mat.select-theme($_light-theme);
  // ... removed for brevity
}

Looking at the forwarded mixins from Material I don't understand what I'm missing since I'm using all the mixins that all-components uses as a starting point to verify it's working which would then be trimmed down. This also appears to be what the docs say for applying a theme to components - https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#applying-a-theme-to-components.
Example stackblitz with menu component, and similar issue with select, datepicker, etc

I think there is some manual error, please check this stackblitz showing the individual themes working fine, maybe you are just missing the menu-theme or something, anyway if issue persists, please share back the stackblitz with the issue replicated for checking

@NarenMurali added a stackblitz with an example of the menu

It looks like a bug to me, the analysis is as below.
When you have generated theme set, then the CSS variable --mat-menu-container-color is missing. This must be a bug

Feel free to raise a bug on angular components github for this.
Even if you have the default @include mat.all-component-themes($light-theme); the bug is still present.
Stackblitz Demo
